# Multiple option colors with Multiple Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have multiple select boxes which will be added dynamically.

I have 4 options under the selection boxes, each color coded. It works fine with one select box. If i have multiple select boxes then the color coding is not working. Please help!

Heres the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/p49g8p9h/

**THE HTML**

```
    <tr>
    <td class="tg-7khl">MAV_01</td>
    <td class="tg-7khl">Maveric Poster</td>
    <td class="tg-7khl">Maveric</td>
    <td class="tg-7khl">PRE,VIN,MUK</td>
    <td class="tg-7khl">14 Aug 2015</td>
    <td class="tg-7khl">
        <select id="stat" class="redText" style="padding: 3px; display:block;">
            <option class="redText">Yet to start</option>
            <option class="orangeText">In Progress</option>
            <option class="blueText">Waiting</option>
            <option class="greenText">To invoice</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-7khl red">from 12 Aug 2015</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your code.

1) You have duplicate IDs for select element. IDs must be unique. You can rather use same class name. and target elements by classname instead.

2) You are using object of get elements in click handler. You should rather use current element context `this` in handler.

**Full Snippet:**

```
var selectele = document.getElementsByClassName('stat');
  for(var i=0;i<selectele.length;i++)
    selectele[i].onchange = function () {
      this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
    }
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oxr4g7zh/)**

Answer (score 0):

check this working updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p49g8p9h/7/) you have duplicating id so this was not working you can do it with class also

```
var select = document.getElementById('stat');
select.onchange = function () {
    select.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
}
var select1 = document.getElementById('stat1');
select1.onchange = function () {
    select1.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
}
var select2 = document.getElementById('stat2');
select2.onchange = function () {
    select2.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` should be unique for each elements. Use `class` `redText` instead `id` like following.

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('redText');

for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    select[i].onchange = function () {
        this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p49g8p9h/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for multiple elements which is the cause to fail getting all element by id.

change all id to class as shown below -

```
<select class="stat redText" style="padding: 3px; display:block;">
```

Use `this.className` so that it will take only current select box for which value changed

```
var select = document.getElementsByClassName('stat');
for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
  select[i].onchange = function () {
    this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
  }
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p49g8p9h/12/)**